# Как правильно оформить запрос к БД

Tags: sql, sqlite, perl

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как грамотно сделать запрос к базе.
Есть скрипт:

```
my $dbqueryAllData = $db->prepare("select * ,sum(f6),sum(f7),sum(f8),sum(f9),sum(f10),sum(f11),sum(f12),sum(f13),sum(replace((f14),'+-','-')) from DPTDAT where f1 in (?,?,?,?...40000-120000штук...?,?,?,?) group by f1 order by f1");
$dbqueryAllData->execute(@rowPRODGRPs);
```

Как грамотно оформить запрос, чтобы не писать огромное количество знаков "?"
Сделать запросы в цикле по несколько штук? Или есть способ уместить все в один запрос?

Благодаря комментариям @Mike
Решение нашлось, обычны запрос безе where.

```
select * ,sum(f3),sum(f3),sum(f4),sum(f5),sum(f6),sum(f7),sum(f8),sum(replace((f9),'+-','-')) from PLSDAT group by f1 order by f1;
```

Comment: Для начала надо понять ради чего вообще это делается и что скрывается за этими знаками `?` сколько всего записей в таблице и сколько из них обрабатывается программой за один раз

Comment: Под знаками ? скрывается числа в формате 46070517965460645. Записей в таблице около 60000. Обработать за 1 запрос хочется сразу все.

Comment: А откуда программа их изначально берет, откуда то извне. Не из базы данных ? Закономерностей в числах нет, они не подряд, диапазоном их невозможно задать ? Вы написали что у вас 40к знаков ?, т.е. вы за один раз обрабатываете 2/3 всей таблицы ? Если так - может получить все 60к на клиента и выбрать какие вам нужны (главное конечно не злоупотреблять, выбирать скажем 60к ради обработки 1к уже как то напряжно)

Comment: Программа изначально их берет из базы. Закономерностей в числах нет, и диапазон задать не возможно есть вероятность, что среди чисел в определенный момент времени могут появляться значения с латинскими буквами. Количество знаков вопроса может быть и другим, оно может измениться(в большую сторону но диапазон примерно от 40к до 120к), просто хотелось бы узнать сам принцип от которого потом можно будет отталкиваться. Нужно получить все тк нужно обработать сразу всю таблицу.

Comment: Если надо обработать всю таблицу - вообще не задавайте условия where и ни одного `?` соответственно, запрос вернет все сгруппировав и отсортировав. А если эти числа изначально были взяты из этой же самой базы - то стоит задуматься об объединении того запроса который их изначально получил с вот этим, в один единый SQL-запрос

Comment: Воистину, все гениально просто.

Answer (score 0):

Я сталкивался с ситуацией, когда слишком большое колличество "?" в операторе in вызывало падения. Это было связано с особенностями драйвера БД. Так что совет 1: используйте связывание через join. Если не получается то совет 2: пишите значения прямо в sql.